# Sharepoint 2010 - Drag and drop interface

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, user-interface, drag-and-drop

We use Sharepoint 2010 in our enterprise. And I want to create a way of having role based interfaces. And letting users drag and drop the interface to their likings.

For example, if a user is member of certain group -> Show particular div
This would result in an interface that consists of a certain amount of divs or "boxes" that the user can move around on the page. Similar to how the start screen works in Windows 8.

How doable is this? I reckon I can use jQuery to do the actual drag and drop functionality. But how can the changes be saved for that particular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page personalization is a standard feature of Sharepoint 2010. User can customize their view by dragging and dropping web parts and adding new web parts. Please, see this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeJltx2miUA. Maybe this feature will fit your requirements.

Comment: It's still a bit wonky for users to actually do. Our users have little or no knowledge of computers in general. So making Interfaces as simple as possible is key for us. If will however take a look at the built-in possibilities, allthough I don't think they suffice.

Comment: I think, you can base your functionality on a standard personalization feature in drag'n'drop and data storage parts.